# Find a specific paper on information retrieval method supporting literature research searching not by keywords but by documents

Tags: reference-request, bibliometrics, literature-search

About 2012, I did a literature research on the following topic but unfortunately lost my results. Specifically one paper comes repeatedly to my mind, therefore maybe someone knows about this or subsequent research.

The research question of that paper was about information retrieval, specifically full text mining of scientific literature to automate literature research.

The researchers built a custom spider/search engine which takes as input not a set of keywords but set of documents.

They described that this approach allowed them to find relevant branches of research they were not aware of.

Which paper was it and/or what is state of the art regarding this topic?

Comment: Can you provide any more information about the paper or literature search? I.e. keywords, approximate name of author or title, color of the journal header, etc.? A google scholar reveals only a few papers: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C21&q=%22full+text+mining%22+%22automation%22+%22search+engine%22+%22keyword%22&btnG=    //// However, I feel as if the current question is too broad, ranging from 'what is this paper' to 'what is the state of the art in this domain'? Certainly the latter might be determined via a new review of recent literature in relevant journals...

Comment: I can't. The question is about specific paper.

Comment: This is a "content of research" question and should be closed.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not the older article that you are looking for, but a colleague of mine published an article that shows how to identify the most relevant literature using free biblilometric tools such as [VOSviewer](https://www.vosviewer.com). That is, by beginning with a topic search on a citation database (e.g. Scopus or Web of Science), you can identify the most relevant body of literature based on cocitations and other bibliometrics:

> Walsh, I., & Renaud, A. (2017). Reviewing the literature in the IS field: Two bibliometric techniques to guide readings and help the interpretation of the literature. Systèmes d’Information et Management. Retrieved from https://www.researchgate.net/publication/316560668_Reviewing_the_literature_in_the_IS_field_Two_bibliometric_techniques_to_guide_readings_and_help_the_interpretation_of_the_literature

Perhaps you'll get lucky and the original article you're looking for might be in their reference list.